# HTTP not returning JSON in Ruby

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, http

I have this code:

```
base_twitter_url = 'http://cdn.api.twitter.com/1/urls/count.json?url='
raw_url = base_twitter_url + 'http://www.google.com' 
url = URI.parse(raw_url)
req = Net::HTTP::Get.new(url.to_s)
res = Net::HTTP.start(url.host, url.port) {|http|
  http.request(req)
}
p res.body
```

Which I expect to return a json, because when doing it from the browser as: `https://cdn.api.twitter.com/1/urls/count.json?url=http://www.google.com` I get a JSON back.

But no luck. What am I doing wrong here?

**EDIT:**

I just tried this from a raw ruby file, and it works fine.  However when doing it from a Rails controller action, I don't get any results.  Fail to see why.

Comment: So what do you get back instead?

Comment: I don't see anything if I do res.inspect

Comment: What is the response status code (`res.code`)?  That's typically the first place to look when you're debugging HTTP stuff.

Answer (score 2):

Your code is going to an HTTP endpoint, whereas in the browser you're going to an HTTPS endpoint (i.e. using SSL).  That particular address, when going via HTTP, returns a redirect to the HTTPS version.